# Ruby JSON.pretty_generate ... is pretty unpretty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems

I can't seem to get `JSON.pretty_generate()` to actually generate pretty output in Rails.

I'm using Rails 2.3.5 and it seems to automatically load the JSON gem.  Awesome.  While using `script/console` this does indeed produce JSON:

```
some_data = {'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 20, 'cow' => [1, 2, 3, 4], 'moo' => {'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow'}}
some_data.to_json
=> "{\"cow\":[1,2,3,4],\"moo\":{\"cat\":\"meow\",\"dog\":\"woof\"},\"foo\":1,\"bar\":20}"
```

But this doesn't produce *pretty output*:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(some_data)
=> "{\"cow\":[1,2,3,4],\"moo\":{\"cat\":\"meow\",\"dog\":\"woof\"},\"foo\":1,\"bar\":20}"
```

The only way I've found to generate it is to use `irb` and to load the "Pure" version:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json/pure'
some_data = {'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 20, 'cow' => [1, 2, 3, 4], 'moo' => {'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow'}}
JSON.pretty_generate(some_data)
=> "{\n  \"cow\": [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3,\n    4\n  ],\n  \"moo\": {\n    \"cat\": \"meow\",\n    \"dog\": \"woof\"\n  },\n  \"foo\": 1,\n  \"bar\": 20\n}"
```

BUT, what I really want is Rails to produce this.  Does anyone have any tips why I can't get the generator in Rails to work correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: @Amy, there seems to be some inconsistencies in your examples. `{"cow"=>[1, 2, 3, 4], ...` isn't valid JSON. JSON uses `:` in place of Ruby's `=>`. Can you paste actual output?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was cutting-and-pasting from a terminal where I had put the output through a puts().  The above is the exact output from script/console and irb.

Comment: Could you explain how you get the second output? (i.e. where is the line JSON.pretty_generate(some_data))

Comment: @egarcia: If you enter the console via script/console and run the first example, then you run the second example immediately thereafter it should do that.  Or at least on my computer it's doing it.

I tried the above examples only with version 2.3.5; I noticed on an app running Rails version 2.2.2 and in that the JSON library wasn't even loaded ("NameError: uninitialized constant JSON").

Answer (score 23):

To generate pretty JSON output it appears that you're only missing a `puts` call.

The data:

```
some_data = {'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 20, 'cow' => [1, 2, 3, 4], 'moo' => {'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow'}}
```

Calling only `JSON.pretty_generate`:

```
> JSON.pretty_generate some_data
 => "{\n  \"foo\": 1,\n  \"bar\": 20,\n  \"cow\": [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3,\n    4\n  ],\n  \"moo\": {\n    \"dog\": \"woof\",\n    \"cat\": \"meow\"\n  }\n}"
```

Adding a `puts` into the mix:

```
> puts JSON.pretty_generate some_data
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 20,
  "cow": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
  "moo": {
    "dog": "woof",
    "cat": "meow"
  }
}
```

Comment: The output that OP provided doesn't contain any `\n`s, so `puts` is not going to change anything.

Comment: @DamianNowak I'm not sure if I understand what your objection is. In my example I'm using the same input as the OP specified and then demonstrating pretty output through the use of `puts` in irb. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: `pretty_generate` doesn't work for OP. There are no `\n` or indent spaces in OP's output, as you can see. So `puts` is not going to change anything.

Comment: @Geoff Petrie You can see the \n in first part of your code that are absent in OP's output. That is why the puts will not change anything for OP.

Answer (score 8):

I use Rails 2.3.8 and installed the JSON gem (`gem install json`). `JSON.pretty_generate` now does nicely in script/console:

```
>> some_data = {'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 20, 'cow' => [1, 2, 3, 4], 'moo' => {'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow'}}
=> {"cow"=>[1, 2, 3, 4], "moo"=>{"cat"=>"meow", "dog"=>"woof"}, "foo"=>1, "bar"=>20}
>> JSON.pretty_generate(some_data)
=> "{\n  \"cow\": [\n    1,\n    2,\n    3,\n    4\n  ],\n  \"moo\": {\n    \"cat\": \"meow\",\n    \"dog\": \"woof\"\n  },\n  \"foo\": 1,\n  \"bar\": 20\n}"
```

Comment: Go figure.  It works now.  I also recently upgraded to 2.3.8.

Comment: @Amy, doesn't it mean this answer should be the accepted one?