# Read nested hash and generate separate hash of similar structure

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash

I am trying to read a JSON schema, parse specific content, and generate a new Hash with the same nested structure.

I am able to traverse the original schema however, when I then try to create the new nested Hash, it's flattened.

This is what I have so far:

```
require 'json'
@schema = JSON.parse("{
  "fields": [
    {
      "group": "common",
      "key": "1st_level"
    },
    {
      "object": "nested",
      "key": "order",
      "fields": [
        {
          "group": "common",
          "key": "2nd_level_1"
        },
        {
          "object": "nested",
          "key": "order2",
          "fields": [
            {
              "group": "common",
              "key": "3rd_level_1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
")
@event_output = Hash.new

def parse_config(fields)
    if fields["group"].downcase == "common"
      @response = "HIT HERE"
    else
      @response = "INVALID GROUP"
    end
    return @response
end

def loop_params(parent, key, schema)
  @new_output = Hash.new
  @parent = parent
  schema["fields"].each do |fields|
    if fields["object"].nil? & !fields["group"].nil?
      @key = fields["key"]
      @repsonse = parse_config(fields)
      @new_output[@key] = @repsonse
      if key != ""
        @parent[key] = @new_output
      else
        @parent = @new_output
      end
    else
      print @parent
      @key = fields["key"]
      loop_params(@parent, @key, fields)
    end
  end
  return @parent
end
@event_output = loop_params(@event_output, "", @schema)
print "\n FINAL OUTPUT \n"
print @event_output
```

The output from this is:

```
{
    "1st_level"=>"HIT HERE",
    "order"=>{
        "2nd_level_1"=>"HIT HERE"
    },
    "order2"=>{
        "3rd_level_1"=>"HIT HERE"
    }
}
```

which is close but I want:

```
{
    "1st_level"=>"HIT HERE",
    "order"=>{
        "2nd_level_1"=>"HIT HERE",
        "order2"=>{
            "3rd_level_1"=>"HIT HERE"
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
def loop_params(schema)
  new_parent = Hash.new

  schema["fields"].each do |field|
    new_key = field["key"]

    if !field["group"].nil? && field["object"].nil?
      new_parent[new_key] = parse_config(field)
    else
      new_parent[new_key] = loop_params(field)
    end
  end

  new_parent
end
```

There are a few issues in your code that might be causing errors. Using `@` to declare a variable makes it an instance variable, which means its value will persist after the function completes. Since we can't see the rest of your program, I don't know if you need all or any of them, but I wrote my solution without them.

A few other things to note:

```
if fields["object"].nil? & !fields["group"].nil?
```

your use of `&` is actually the bitwise operator `and`, rather than the conditional `and`. Use `&&` instead.

Also, if you use `puts` instead of `print`, `puts` will automatically append a `"\n"` for you, which is a nice convenience to keep in mind.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. And thank you for the tips regarding the snippet of code I have shown you, I will take those into consideration when working on the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into `pretty_generate`. See "[Ruby JSON.pretty_generate ... is pretty unpretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567670/ruby-json-pretty-generate-is-pretty-unpretty)" and http://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/pretty_generate.

It takes a hash.

Your flattened string might just need to be parsed using `JSON.parse` again.